# how to make a navigation out of images and add text inside the image?

Tags: html, css, navigation, web

Yuhg jjgghjj hhngbjg ggf. fbg. Ghhp

Comment: Edit your question and post your efforts.

Comment: SO is no "who can do it for me"-service. You have the answer you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button {
  background: url(http://agnesvaldovinos.com/images/bubble.png) no-repeat 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 61px;
  height: 61px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 126px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-indent: -.5em;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="button">My button</a>
```

Regarding the requirement you added in your comment, you will have to slice the image in two parts and use the so-called **[sliding-doors technique](http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors)**. Also, your `a` tag will need another tag inside it, e.g. a `span`, to be able to apply this technique.

> http://alistapart.com/article/slidingdoors

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bdLKKb

Comment: Read my answer and the referred link at alistapart.